# flutter nfc manager, When I click the button to authenticate my tag, nothing happens

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, nfc

I use an Ntag216 NFC card and flutter nfc manager plugin [(https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_manager)] and I try to authenticate myself with a password, I manage to connect but in a weird way, I put the card on the back of the phone and the phone detects my beacon, I enter the password, when I click on the button nothing happens and I have no error but when I disconnect the beacon and I reconnect it my function is executed without my clicking on the button. I don't understand or maybe it's me the problem, I need help please

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  late TextEditingController password;

  ValueNotifier<dynamic> result = ValueNotifier("PLEASE PLACE THE CARD ON THE BACK OF THE DEVICE");


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    NfcManager.instance.startSession(onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {

      debugPrint(tag.data.toString());

      result.value = "An NFC card is present, Enter your password";
      NfcManager.instance.stopSession();

    }, pollingOptions: {NfcPollingOption.iso14443},);

    password = TextEditingController();

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    password.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        //backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: const Text("NTAG216"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ValueListenableBuilder<dynamic>(
                  valueListenable: result,
                  builder: (context, value, _) => Text(value, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.deepPurple),),
                ),

                const SizedBox(height: 40,),
                TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  controller: password,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    label: Text("Your password"),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 35,),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: _tagAuthentication,
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  shadowColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                  elevation: 3,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  minimumSize: const Size(double.infinity, 50),
                ),
                  child: const Text("VALIDATE", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _tagAuthentication() async {

    if(password.text.isEmpty || password.text == "") {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('Enter your password'),));
      return;
    }
    String pass = password.text.trim();
    
    NfcManager.instance.startSession(onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {

      debugPrint('tag ->$tag');
      NfcA? nfca = NfcA.from(tag);

      if(nfca == null) {
        result.value = 'Tag is not available';
        await NfcManager.instance.stopSession(errorMessage: result.value.toString());
        return;
      }

      try {
        result.value = "Authentication in progress...";
        final data = pass.codeUnits;
        final bytes = Uint8List.fromList([0x1B, data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]]);
        final response = await nfca.transceive(data: bytes);

        if(response.length == 2) {
          result.value = "Authentication successful";
          debugPrint(response.toString());
        } else {
          result.value = "Authentication failed";
        }

      } catch (e) {
        //result.value = e.toString();
        result.value = "Authentication failed";
        await NfcManager.instance.stopSession(errorMessage: result.value.toString());
        return;
      }

      await NfcManager.instance.stopSession();
    }, pollingOptions: {NfcPollingOption.iso14443},);
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you resolve this?